# What is the gray question below another question in the first post review queue?

Tags: discussion, first-post-review

Just came across a gray question below another question in the review queue? What is that and why is it there?

[image]

Comment: That's not another question, that the question to the answer you're reviewing. First post doesn't mean "first question". An answer is also a post. The pop-up even says "This is the __first answer__ posted by a new user".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The First Posts queue has you review both questions and answers. In this case you're reviewing the *answer* at the top, and the bottom is the question it's supposed to be answering.